# I can't make permutations using a recursive function in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a recursive function which prints all possible permutations of a given set.

```
perm = []  # list to make permutations
S = {1,2,3,4}  # set of elements which have not used for the permutation yet

def make_perm():
  if not S:
    print(perm)
  else:
    for x in S:
      perm.append(x)
      S.remove(x)
      make_perm()
      perm.pop()
      S.add(x)
      
make_perm()
```

However, this program doesn't work: it outputs `[1,2,3,4]` only.
What is the cause?

(Add) I want the program to output as follows.

```
> [1,2,3,4]
> [1,2,4,3]
> [1,3,2,4]
> [1,3,4,2]
      ︙
```

When it is complied with PyPy3(7.3.0), it outputs `[1,2,3,4]` only.
But when it is complied with Python3(3.8.2), it outputs as follows.

```
> [1,2,3,4]
> [1,2,4,3]
> [1,3,2,4]
> [1,3,2,4]
> [1,3,4,2]
      ︙
```

Some outputs are duplicating. I am very confused that these outputs are incorrect and different :(.

Comment: And what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Note that any notion of set order is arbitrary - that includes iteration and insertion order. There is no guarantee that removing/adding to the set while iterating has well-defined or even stable behavior; by extension, any algorithm using this has implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are modifying `S` while iterating over it. You should iterate over a copy

```
for x in S.copy():
    perm.append(x)
    S.remove(x)
    make_perm()
    perm.pop()
    S.add(x)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[3, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 4]
[3, 2, 4, 1]
[3, 4, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 2]
[4, 2, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 1, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Note that `set` doesn't guarantee the order, you should use `list` instead

```
S = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for x in S[:]:
    perm.append(x)
    S.remove(x)
    make_perm()
    perm.pop()
    S.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do `perm.append(x)` you append an item from `S` and not a permutation so after 4 times, `S` is empty and you obtain `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list) how to generate all the permutations of a list (very similar in case of set).

Comment: But the original function does work — it prints all permutations. After e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is obtained, it is printed and the numbers are added back into the set.

Comment: I am not quite following how this answers the question. "after 4 times, S is empty and you obtain ``[1, 2, 3, 4]``" is kind of the point – ``[1, 2, 3, 4]`` is one permutation. Then the function proceeds with the next permutation.

Answer (score -1):

not answering the question, but I saw that you use code that does not follow the standards on how such a function should work.
Currently, your function requires 2 fields to be set **outside** your function.
You don't want that - functions should only rely on their arguments.
Also, instead of printing all permutations, you should `return` them instead. This allows you to later work with the permutations.

```py
def make_perm(iterable):
  if not iterable: return null
  else:
    permutations = []
    for elem in iterable:
      #push to permutations
    return permutations
      
s = {1, 2, 3, 4}
permutations = make_perm(s)
print(permutations)
```

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and are fine with using a module, take a look into [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)